# Get all the values from nested JSON arrays in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql, unnest

I want to extract all the `app_indexe` in `abc` array using the raw query. The database I'm using PostgreSQL 10.9. I'm successfully able to extract till `abc` key. what I'm able to get is by passing the index number of the array. but I want all the app_index.

without index:

`select v_info->'abc' from table1`

with index:
`select v_info->'abc'->>0 from table1`

```
{
        "id": 1406711300166,
        "abc": [ 
            {
                "am": "1.74",
                "am_set": {
                    "sh_mon": {
                        "am": "1.74",
                        "cur_code": "ABC"
                    },
                    "pre_money": {
                        "amount": "1.74",
                        "code": "ABC"
                    }
                },
                "app_index": 0
            },
           {
                "am": "1.74",
                "am_set": {
                    "sh_mon": {
                        "am": "1.74",
                        "cur_code": "ABC"
                    },
                    "pre_money": {
                        "amount": "1.74",
                        "code": "ABC"
                    }
                },
                "app_index": 1
            }
        ],
        "xyx": 0,
        "zyx": "random var"
    }
```

what I need is all the values in the `app_index` of `abc`.

output

```
abc_index
----------
0
1
```

Comment: Please show us the result that you expect, as tabular text.

Comment: @GMB I have edited my question. you can get a rough idea.

Comment: What version of postgres are you on

Comment: @HaleemurAli PostgreSQL 10.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can unnest the array with `json(b)_array_elements()` and then just access the value of attribute  `app_index`:

```
select el -> 'app_index' abc_index
from mytable t
cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements(t.v_info -> 'abc') a(el)
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=8ee2d59ff2860fa9d2166dfc19fc8406)**:

```
| abc_index |
| :-------- |
| 0         |
| 1         |
```